# Data analysis: describing graphs (vocabulary)

Tags: dataset

I have to describe graphs, but I'm lacking in vocabulary (English not being my mother tongue), I hope there wasn't a previous open topic. If not it may be useful for others.

- how would you call a bump in a curve, where endpoints are similar a seen on the pointed red lines.
- How can I describe the gap as seen on the solid red line
- how can I descrive the peak as seen on the yellow solide line
- synonym for upward/increase which is not growth
- synonym for downward/decrease.
- Moreover, would it be right to say that for eg. (yellow solid line) the decrease starts at +2, but reached its peak at +1 ?

Each curve represent cumulative average price changes 5 days before and after an event (day 0).
[image]

Comment: This question would really benefit from a figure depicting the different examples that you are asking about.

Comment: @Sycorax, thanks for your reply. I have updated my question with a picture :)

Comment: Could you describe which line in the figure depict which case?

Comment: @JanKukacka I've updated :)

Comment: I meant to describe how are the lines in the plot related to the three terms that you are looking for. E.g. does the red line represent the bump you mention in the first bulletpoint?

Comment: @JanKukacka thanks for your quick reply, I've re updated !

Comment: First thing first, please rescale that y axis. If your data vary no more than +/- 0.02 your audience may doubt if you are expanding the y axis to make things look more similar than they are.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight thanks for your reply. I've used this axis as I have about 15 other graphs that I am using to make an analysis, and to compare graph between them it makes thing easier :)

Comment: I see! That makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

That's the vocab. I'd use, I'm pretty sure there are other similar terms too.

- uptick
- ... the dotted red line ...
- upward/downward trend
- the downward trend started at time -2 and reached its bottom/lowest value at time 1.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So how would I describe the effect of -1, as this at -1 that values are starting to decrease ?

Comment: well, usually you'd have a date or something there, not a random number. If you absolutely HAD to use a number, label them as "at timestep 1, 2, etc..... something happened". However, business/marketing guys and clients are easily distracted, so that's a bad idea.